# Retrieve column header from specific row in excel using ADO and VB.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, ado.net, vba

I have an app where a user uploads a spreadsheet and specifies the sheetname and row number for the header row. I need the app to extract the column names from that specified row. I was able to get it to work returning the top row. How would i speficy that the column names i want should be on row(x)

```
     Dim ExcelConn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim ExcelTable As DataTable = Nothing
        Dim dr As DataRow
        Dim sheet_found As Boolean = False
        ExcelConn = New system.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & file & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        End If

        'open the file
        ExcelConn.Open()
        ExcelTable = ExcelConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "Table"})

        'make sure there is a matching sheet name
        For Each dr In ExcelTable.Rows
            If dr("TABLE_NAME").ToString() = sheet & "$" Then
                sheet_found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If sheet_found = False Then
            MesgBox("the sheet name specified in the header (" + sheet + ") was not found")
            ExcelConn.Close()
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Dim sheet_name As String = Nothing
            sheet_name = "[" & sheet & "$]"
            Dim cmd1 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select * From " & sheet_name, ExcelConn)
            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From " & sheet_name, ExcelConn)
            Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
            Dim dc As DataColumn
            da.Fill(ds)
            For Each dc In ds.Tables(0).Columns 'this returns col names fine from first row. how would i tell it to get names from 2nd or 3rd row, etc. The integer var is passed in. i just need to know how to specify that it is row(x)
                header_row = LCase(RTrim(header_row + "|" + dc.ColumnName))
            Next
            MsgBox(header_row)
            ExcelConn.Close()
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know (checked that issue in the past) there is no way to select  a table with `System.Data.OleDb` from excel file using SQL query **if headers are not placed in row 1**. the solution for me is to delete all the rows above the header row before querying the worksheet - just opening the workbook with `Microsoft.Office.Interop` deleting the extra rows, closing it and than querying it.

Excel is a very powerful tool but was never designed to behave like database (sql server or access file for example).

Answer (score 0):

There are some known limitations to use the JET/ACE drivers to access data in Excel sheets, as jonathana has pointed out.

As an alternative, I'd like to offer our Excel ADO.NET Provider. With it, you get all of the SQL access to your Excel data that you're accustomed to from the JET/ACE drivers, but with more flexibility in how that data is arranged in Excel.

In your example, you could submit a query like the following to denote that the headers are placed in row 4:

```
SELECT * FROM Sheet1#A4:**
```

Using our provider, your code would look similar to the following:

```
Dim ExcelConn As System.Data.CData.Excel.ExcelConnection
Dim ExcelTable As DataTable = Nothing
Dim dr As DataRow
Dim sheet_found As Boolean = False
ExcelConn = New System.Data.CData.Excel.ExcelConnection("Excel File=" & file & ";")

'open the file
ExcelConn.Open()
ExcelTable = ExcelConn.GetSchema("Tables")

'make sure there is a matching sheet name
For Each dr In ExcelTable.Rows
  If dr("Table_Name").ToString() = sheet Then
    sheet_found = True
    Exit For
  End If
Next
If sheet_found = False Then
  MesgBox("the sheet name specified in the header (" + sheet + ") was not found")
  ExcelConn.Close()
  Exit Sub
Else
  Dim sheet_name As String = Nothing
  'Here, I assume that header_row indicates the row that contains the headers
  sheet_name = "[" & sheet & "#A" & header_row & ":**]"
  Dim cmd1 As New System.Data.CData.Excel.ExcelCommand("Select * From " & sheet_name, ExcelConn)
  Dim da As New System.Data.CData.Excel.ExcelDataAdapter("Select * From " & sheet_name, ExcelConn)
  Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
  Dim dc As DataColumn
  da.Fill(ds)
  For Each dc In ds.Tables(0).Columns
    'I wasn't sure what this code was meant to accomplish, but at this point, 
    'dc.ColumnName contains the column names from header_row
  Next
  ExcelConn.Close()
End If
```

We have a [blog post](http://www.cdata.com/blog/data_connectivity/20160629-feature-excel-drivers) on our site with more information on our provider and you can [download a free trial](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/excel/download/ado/) from our site as well.